# How to free memory in function

Tags: c++, memory, sdl, free

So my problem is how to free "Input" and "Output" in this function.

```
void DSprite(
        SDL_Surface* Input, 
                SDL_Surface* Output,
                int InputX, int InputY, 
                int InputWidth, int InputHeight,
                int OutputX, int OutputY,
                bool FollowCamera
               )
{
... code

// Free.

SDL_FreeSurface(Input);
   Input=NULL;
   SDL_FreeSurface(Output);
   Output=NULL;

}
```

Without this free part.
My game memory usage is rising very fast, from 9 000 K to over 200 000 K in 20 seconds! Is this function a problem? It's called every frame many times. How to free it?

But with it.
This doesn't work. After few seconds of running game keeps froze at first frame which is supposed to be drawn. And this error pops out.

```
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in game.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in game.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while game.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.
```

And if it's correct?

```
void DText(TTF_Font *FontIn,const char* TextIn, (...)
{
(...)

SDL_Surface* TextSurf = TTF_RenderText_Solid(FontIn,TextIn,ColorIn);

(...)

//Free

TTF_CloseFont(FontIn);
FontIn=NULL;

SDL_FreeSurface(TextSurf);

free((char*)TextIn);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How the input and ouptut are used for you program? What does the code do (i mean what is ...code) ?
There is definitly something wrong, you give an input and output and free them before returning from the function.

From the variable name, i don't think the Ouput surface needs to be freed. Because it seems to crash when doing the sdl_blit (or sdl_flip if you use double buffer ), because the surface you want to blit is a NULL pointer.

C/C++ memory managment:
There is two type of memory allocation. Static and dynamic.

The static one is when you declare a variable in code

```
int a;
char b;
// Or even SDL strucutre
SDL_Surface Surface;
```

To make it extremly simple, when program will start this memory will be allocated (if i'm not wrong it is what we call the stack memory). The program will handle those variables memory. So you should never try to manually free those variables, it will cause your program to crash.

The second memory allocation is the dynamic one. It allow you two allocate memory (in the heap memory) according to your need. It can be done with various method like malloc, calloc, etc... ( the new function is only available in C++). You need to deallocate the memory you allocated eitherway you will create what is called a memory leak.

```
//Example
int* anArray = new int[10]; // I allocated a table of 10 char
// To free
delete  [] anArray;
```

Concerning what you ask, creating a global variable `SDL_Surface surface`.
SDL_Surface is a structure, which mean it is a "box" containing variables. Because of how SDL works a SDL surface should be created using `SDL_CreateRGBSurface` or other function of this kind. And also because of how it works you need to use `SDL_FreeSurface` to free the surface (basically because the SDL_Surface contain a dynamic array of pixel, so to make managment easier, the SDL guys created a function to cleanup a previously created surface).

So a SDL_Surface is a big variable, and because it is dynamically allocated you use a pointer for variables of type SDL_Surface.

```
SDL_Surface * mysurface;
```

If you created the variable as global that mean you want to use it in more than one function. So do not free it in a function.

However if you created

```
SDL_Surface mysurface; // No pointer a standard static allocation
```

Do not try to free it

Regards

regards

Comment: Hello. Thanks for answer. I probably just found solution to my answer.  The problem was with >SDL_Surface* TextSurf<. After freeing it, memory usage stopped rising. So I don't have to free vars with * (don't know how it's named) which are in arguments declerations for functions? Only this inside body of function ( { here } ). Is it so?

Comment: The * variables are pointers, which means address to memory. When you allocate memory with default allocator like malloc or new, or special one from SDL (those are factory though), you need to free it if you don't use it anymore. If you don't do it the memory is still locked by the program.

Comment: If you free memory that will still be used, that will cause your program to crash.

Comment: So if I have : "void Func(SDL_Surface* Output)" function with "SDL_FreeSurface(Output)" at the end of function and I have global var "SDL_Surface Surface" and I use Func(Surface) it frees my global var ("SDL_Surface Surface")? Right?

Comment: You confuse dynamic and static allocation, i'll update my post to explain more

Comment: Oh, yes. My bad. In place of "SDL_Surface Surface" I meant "SDL_Surface * Surface". But thank you for this post ;-)